# Помогите выгрузить text с сайта (парсер)

Tags: python

Не получается выгрузить текст из данного класса (если он здесь вообще есть)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно вывести информацию которая идет после title_

```
cars = []
for items in items:
   cars.append({
        #'sticker': items.find('div', class_='float_data').get_text,
        'link': items.find('img', class_='sticker-image', title_="text").get("title") # какой класс мне нужно сюда добавить, или что-то типо того
    })
print(cars)
```

Comment: Приведите свой код в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Импорт модулей:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Парсинг на примере этой страницы:

```
url = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1189286/Помогите-выгрузить-text-с-сайта-парсер' # url страницы

r = requests.get(url) #отправляем HTTP запрос и получаем результат
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text) #Отправляем полученную страницу в библиотеку для парсинга
data = [div for div in soup.find('div', {'class': 'grid s-btn-group js-filter-btn'})]
```

На этом моменте уже есть все нужные div, остается достать из них title:

Например, так:

```
result = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    try:
        result.append(data[i]['title'])
    except TypeError:
        continue

print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
['Сначала недавно обновлённые ответы', 'Ответы отображаются в порядке их публикации', 'Сначала ответы с наивысшим рейтингом']
```

Удачи!